# Azure Machine Learning Studio: cannot deploy model with rpy2 as a dependency

Tags: python, anaconda, rpy2, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to deploy a custom model on Azure Machine Learning Studio that needs rpy2 (Python wrapper for R) to run.  So, I created the following yml file (myenv.yml), specifying the required dependency (besides other stuff),

```
# Conda environment specification. The dependencies defined in this file will
# be automatically provisioned for runs with userManagedDependencies=False.

# Details about the Conda environment file format:
# https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#create-env-file-manually

name: project_environment

dependencies:
  # The python interpreter version.
  # Currently Azure ML only supports 3.5.2 and later.
- python=3.6.2    
- pip:
  - azureml-train-automl-runtime==1.8.0.post1
  - inference-schema
  - azureml-explain-model==1.8.0
  - azureml-defaults==1.8.0
  - rpy2==3.3.5
- dill==0.3.2
- numpy>=1.16.0,<=1.16.2
- pandas>=0.21.0,<=0.23.4
- scikit-learn>=0.19.0,<=0.20.3
- py-xgboost<=0.90
- fbprophet==0.5
- psutil>=5.2.2,<6.0.0

channels:
- anaconda
- conda-forge
```

and then ran the following script (based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-troubleshoot-deployment):

```
from azureml.core.environment import Environment
from azureml.core.model import Model, InferenceConfig
from azureml.core import Workspace
from azureml.core.webservice import AciWebservice

ws = Workspace.from_config()
model = Model(workspace = ws, name = 'test-rpy2') # this is my (registered) model that needs rpy2 to run

# create inference configuration based on the requirements defined in the YAML
myenv = Environment.from_conda_specification(name = "myenv", file_path = "myenv.yml")

inference_config = InferenceConfig(entry_script = "score.py", environment = myenv) # score.py: my custom scoring file where rpy2 is imported

# deploy the model
aci_config = AciWebservice.deploy_configuration(cpu_cores = 1, memory_gb = 1)

service = Model.deploy(workspace         = ws,
                       name              = 'test-rpy2',
                       models            = [model],
                       inference_config  = inference_config,
                       deployment_config = aci_config)

service.wait_for_deployment(show_output=True)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
    Error: rpy2 in API mode cannot be built without R in the PATH or R_HOME defined. Correct this or force ABI mode-only by defining the environment variable RPY2_CFFI_MODE=ABI
```

I expected that the issue would be fixed by adding the line

```
myenv.environment_variables['RPY2_CFFI_MODE'] = 'ABI'
```

right after the definition of myenv, but the exact same error shows up again.

Does anyone have any idea on how to make it work?

Answer (score 3):

To me, the message is saying that you can't use `rpy2` because R is not installed in the Docker image. I think the fix is that You'll have to add R as a conda dependency. Here's some [guidance](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/using-r-language/). I'm not an expert on `R`+`conda` but try adding `r-base` and `r-essentials` as conda deps.

another note -- I strongly recommend minimizing conda dependencies when using the `azureml-sdk` because `azureml-sdk` is only available on PyPI. [This doc](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment) explains the challenges well. Below is my guess on what it would look like, but i'm not confident on the mapping b/w anaconda and pip packagenames/versions.

```yaml
dependencies:
- python=3.6.2
- r-base 
- r-essentials
- py-xgboost<=0.90   
- pip:
  - azureml-train-automl-runtime==1.8.0.post1
  - inference-schema
  - azureml-explain-model==1.8.0
  - azureml-defaults==1.8.0
  - rpy2==3.3.5
  - dill==0.3.2
  - numpy>=1.16.0,<=1.16.2
  - pandas>=0.21.0,<=0.23.4
  - scikit-learn>=0.19.0,<=0.20.3
  - fbprophet==0.5
  - psutil>=5.2.2,<6.0.0

channels:
- anaconda
- conda-forge
```

Comment: Thanks for your hints; adding r-base and r-essentials actually solves the error, although I had to remove conda-forge from the channels (otherwise, it would get stuck on "Solving environment" indefinitely). Unfortunately, I then get another error inside the scoring script ("cannot read workspace version 3 written by R 3.6.1; need R 3.5.0 or newer"). I tried to fix it by setting r-base=3.6.1 or r-base=3.5.0, but no luck (it fails to build the environment due to package incompatibility issues). I am still trying to figure out what's going wrong

Comment: As for the .yml file, I actually got the template by running "best_run._download_artifact_contents_to_string('outputs/conda_env_v_1_0_0.yml')" (where best_run was the best run from an AutoML experiment in Azure ML Studio) - I don't know why they put all those packages as conda dependencies. By the way, thanks for the additional note and link

Comment: stepping back for a second... is there a particular reason why you'd like to call R from Python? I haven't used it, but there is an [Azure ML SDK for R](https://github.com/Azure/azureml-sdk-for-r), and an [`RScriptStep` for Azure ML Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-pipeline-steps/azureml.pipeline.steps.rscriptstep?view=azure-ml-py). Perhaps the pain of using one of these methods is less than the pain of getting the `rpy2` conda env working?